# How to count two numbers from a CSV file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to `pandas` and I have huge CSV file bytes numbers , I want to compare the value of CSV with two numbers and Count the differences in the number of csv files

```
grouped = df.groupby('a')
grouped.count()
df.groupby(['234355' '18923422']).size()
# df.groupby(['0' '1023']).size()
```

my csv file value

```
600
0
600
272
600
272
1025
2411
272
152507
600
....
```

**expected output :**

```
                    count
234355 - 18923422   2352
0 - 1023            15,233,233
18923423            1
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: i updated my csv value

Comment: I think you need to make a series!

Comment: Thank you for edit, can you add expected output from sample data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) for boolean mask and then count `True`s by `sum`, it is processes like `1`s:

```
out = df['a'].between(0, 1023).sum()
print (out)
8
```